# Cómo puedo consumir un JsonObject desde angular 8?

Tags: json, angular, api, web

necesito consumir un jsonObject desde angular 8, pero no logro obtener el dato que necesito, la api que intento consumir viene así

```
[  //Array
    { //Objeto            
        "Descripcion": //Elemento dentro del objeto.
         ...
        "Detalles": [ //Array
            {
              //Objeto
            }
            ...
            ]
           "Talla": //Elemento dentro del objeto.
        }
    ]
```

necesito consumir el objeto de adentro en este caso detalles, por medio de angular 8, tengo mi código así:

Mi service:

```
  getList(): Observable<Respuesta> {
    return this.http
    .get<Respuesta>(this.base_path)
    .pipe(
      retry(2),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
```

mi modulo así:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.getList();
      }

getList() {
    //get saved list of products
    this.apiService
    .getList()
    .subscribe(
      response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.respuestaData = response;
    });
```

y para imprimir lo normal con un *ngFor

Comment: que te imprime `console.log(response)`? Y que propiedad necesitas saber?

Comment: Hola, esto es modo de aclarar conceptos. No existe tal cosa como *jsonObject* en Javascript. [JSON](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) es un formato de texto, para intercambiar datos entre pares, permite enviar información compleja de forma sencilla (comparado con XML, por ejemplo). Un [Objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabajando_con_objectos) por otro lado, es algo muy diferente de un texto con formato. Cuando te refieras a la data recibida desde alguna fuente, usa sólo el término JSON, y cuando te refieras a un Objeto de JS, no lo llames JSON. Saludos

Comment: @hawks en consola me imprime todo el json que puse arriba, quiero accesar al objeto que está dentro de detalles, por ejemplo, más propiedades, como si fuera otro json de respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

la forma correcta era esta:

el service queda igual.

el modulo cambia a esto:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../../services/api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-inicio',
  templateUrl: './inicio.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./inicio.page.scss'],
})
export class InicioPage implements OnInit {
  respuestaData: any;
  respuestaData2: any;

  constructor( public apiService: ApiService) { 
    this.respuestaData = {};
    this.respuestaData2 = {};
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getList();
    this.getList2();
  }

  getList() {
    //get saved list of products
    this.apiService.getList().subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response[0]);
      this.respuestaData = response[0];
    });
  }
```

y en la vista va esto:

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of respuestaData.pages">
      <div *ngIf="item.heading == 'Acerca de la UNA'">
        <div class="heading">
          <h1>
              {{item.heading}}
          </h1>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes asignar un modelo a tu respuesta para manipular mejor el json, te dejo el ejemplo:
**Component TypeScript**

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.servicios.cargarData().subscribe((res: Principal[]) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.datos = res;
    });
  }
```

**Consumo del servicio**

```
  cargarData(): Observable<Principal[]> {
    const url = `assets/prueba.json`;
    return this.http.get<Principal[]>(url);
  }
```

**JSON que se consume**

```
[
    {
        "Descripcion": "Ejemplo Stack OverFlow",
        "Detalles": [
            {
                "objetos": "Objeto"
            }
        ],
        "Talla": "XL"
    }
]
```

**Html**

```
<div *ngFor='let data of datos'>
  <p> {{data.Descripcion}}</p>

  <div *ngFor='let datosObjeto of data.Detalles'>
    <label> {{datosObjeto.objetos}}</label>
  </div>
  <p><label> {{data.Talla}}</label></p>
</div>
```

Como puedes ver en el html, te deje un ejemplo de como acceder a cada parte del JSON, espero te sirva. 
Si tienes dudas con la implementación, te dejo el código [aquí](https://github.com/CristianSneyderSilva/stackOverflow)